# Rspec controller - object persistence in database/ which instance as tests build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm used to tests building like this:

```
describe "post to refund first time" do
  it "should have 1 refund" do
    post :refund
    Refund.count.should == 1
  end

  describe "post to refund 2nd time" do
    it "should have 2 refunds" do
      post :refund
      Refund.count.should == 1
    end
  end
end
```

Except that spec 2 fails, `Refund.count` is only 1. I inserted a `binding.pry` and indeed the first refund was cleared from memory. Is this normal behavior for Rspec controller tests or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed Rails and RSpec reset the DB on each run. For your test to work, you have to really hit the endpoint 2 times:

```
describe "post to refund first time" do
  it "should have 1 refund" do
    post :refund
    Refund.count.should == 1
  end

  describe "post to refund 2nd time" do
    it "should have 2 refunds" do
      2.times { post :refund }
      Refund.count.should == 2
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: omg ok duh.. sorry i was also being very silly. now i realize of course posting is not the same thing as a `before` block